# Windows Batch - Select name from list

Tags: list, batch-file

I was wondering if it's possible to print a list of, then allow the user to select any name on that list to view, here is the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set maxList=5

::creating variables for different names.
::Filip
set FilipTitle=1
set FilipAge=22
set FilipWeight=80

::Ada
set AdaTitle=0
set AdaAge=20
set AdaWeight=42

::Bob
set BobTitle=1
set BobAge=38
set BobWeight=73

set "names=Filip,Ada,Bob"

::pritning the list of names
:start
echo Which name would you like to see?
for /l %%i in (1; 1; %maxList%) do call :sub %%i
goto check

:sub
for /f "tokens=%1 delims=," %%a in ("%names%") do (
echo %%i. %%a
)
goto :eof

::asking user which name they want to view
:check
set /p nameCheck=
goto %nameCheck%

::printing the stats for the name mentioned
:Filip
echo Age: %FilipAge%
echo Weight: %FilipWeight%
pause
goto start

:Ada
echo Age: %AdaAge%
echo Weight: %AdaWeight%
pause
goto start

:Bob
echo Age: %BobAge%
echo Weight: %BobWeight%
pause
goto start
```

The above code prints the list, but only allows you to view the name by typing the name, is there a way to allow the user to enter the number that corresponds to the name on the list - so 1. would be Filip, 2. Ada and so on?
So instead of typing the name they can enter "1" then to print off the 1st name in the list.

Choice command code:

```
:start
for /l %%i in (1; 1; %maxList%) do call :sub %%i
goto check

:sub
for /f "tokens=%1 delims=," %%a in ("%names%") do (
echo %%i. %%a
)
goto :eof

:check
choice /c 123 /n /m "Which name do you want to view?"
if errorlevel 3 (
goto filip
)
if errorlevel 2 (
goto ada
)
if errorlevel 1 (
goto bob
)
```

Comment: Output the numbers along side the items, and use the `choice` command to ask your end user to select the item from the number. I'm sure if you use `[batch-file]`, `choice` and `menu` as your search criteria, you'll find enough examples to help you.

Comment: @Compo choice command like that? If so it's a good shout by I don't think it will work if I add and remove names from the list - if I remove Filip and add Steve, then the choice command will be all wrong.

Comment: Well that depends upon how you do it, but that's not my decision to make, it's yours. I will say however, in my opinion if using batch files without the aid of another language, or third party tool, it is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Writing the same code several times is not a good choice.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM creating variables for different names.
REM Filip
set FilipTitle=1
set FilipAge=22
set FilipWeight=80

REM Ada
set AdaTitle=0
set AdaAge=20
set AdaWeight=42

REM Bob
set BobTitle=1
set BobAge=38
set BobWeight=73

set "names=Filip,Ada,Bob"
REM build an array of names and the numbers for choice:
set number=0
for %%a in (%names%) do (
  set /a number+=1
  echo !number!: %%a
  set choices=!choices!!number!
  set "name_!number!=%%a"
)
:start
choice /c %choices% /m "Enter your choice "
set name=!name_%errorlevel%!
REM display result:
echo Name: %name%
echo Age: !%name%Age!
echo Title: !%name%Title!
echo Weight: !%name%Weight!
goto :start
```